# How is Linq-to-Sql abused?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I hear a lot of linq-to-sql bashing and how people will unknowingly abuse it. But how is linq-to-sql being abused?

**Update**
If someone can give me clear examples of how it's abused that would be very helpful. References to blogs/tutorials would be very helpful as well. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest mistakes to make is to create a query which results in a loop of calls to the database instead of a single call returning all the data. For this reason it's worth checking what sql commands are hitting the database either in the debugger or with a trace.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that LINQ->SQL can be abused just like poorly written inline SQL/ADO.NET/SPs or what have you.

Alot of what you might have heard is how LINQ itself might be abused.

Answer (score 1):

I think one example of it being misused would be as a total replacement for SQL in views or stored procedures on the server, and therefore potentially more lax security on the database server.

Answer (score -1):

Well... if you can write complicated queries with linq-to-sql it's probably because you know SQL syntax and are pretty good at writting the query in SQL in the first place. So why would you use the .NET syntax to write a syntax tree that then another layer of software would translate (perhaps not very efficiently) into SQL for you?
Just write the damn thing in SQL in the first place :-)

Comment: Why?  Because it allows faster development in a single environment.  And 'complicated' linq-to-sql queries are much simpler to write and more succinct than their sql counterparts.

Comment: it's not a single environment. Your syntax gets converted to SQL for you. Also, there are constructs in SQL not incorporated into .NET syntax yet (c# or VB.net). So in a way using LINQ you might be under utilizing the SQL engine.

Comment: I like to use linq-to-sql for a number of reasons. 1) it provides binding support with web controls (even though that's not good practice it saves a lot of time) 2) i can use VS's intellisense 3) I don't have to create stored procedures in sql studio and then manually initializing each of the stored procedure parameters. 4) I can debug in VS Standard edition (only professional version & higher allows you to step in sql server while debug mode). I have a few more reasons but i dont have enough char's to explain them.
Dont take my criticism personally! I love to hear ppl's thoughts/opinions. =)

Comment: Kirk, care to explain why -2 for having a different opinion than yours?

Comment: Not true. My SQL knowlege is very limited, but I can write pretty complex L2S queries. Maybe because I have a good understanding of the _concepts_ behind SQL (set theory). As a benefit, my queries are strongly typed, under source control and also on a (slightly) higher level of abstraction. I guess I could switch to SQL, but all it would give me are longer development times, so why bother?